# $SU(N)$ Theory equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, lie-algebra, variational-calculus

I want to derive the equations of motion from the following Lagrangian:

\begin{align}
L = -(Tr(\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi)-mTr(\phi^2)
\end{align}

Where $\phi = \phi^a T_a$ and $T_a$ are the generators of the group.

i) My first question here is how $\phi$ could be a scalar field. A scalar field does not have components so what should $\phi^a$ mean?

ii) When I want to compute the euler lagrange equations, I have to deal with this trace somehow. So I want to write this lagrangian in index notation so i can differentiate with respect to $\phi, \partial_\mu\phi$.The trace for the mass term for example can be rewritten as:
\begin{align}
Tr(\phi^2)=Tr(\phi^aT_a\phi^bT_b)=\phi^a\phi^b(T_aT_b)^j_j=\phi^a\phi^b(T_a)_ij(T_b)^{ji}=\phi^a\phi^b T_aT_b^T
\end{align}
I am not sure how to differentiate this with respect to $\phi$

Comment: This is not a gauge theory at all.

Comment: It's not even $SU(N)$, its $O(N)$

Comment: Under the transformation $\phi\rightarrow e^{-i\Lambda}\phi e^{i\Lambda}$ this lagrangian is invariant. (Here $\Lambda = \Lambda^aT_a$, where $T_a$ are the generators of the group) Doesn't this mean it is a gauge theory since it is invariant under gauge transformation?

Comment: It is only invariant under this if $\Lambda$ is a constant so it is not a gauge theory. It is a theory with global $O(N)$ or $SO(N)$ invariance. Also its $O(N)$ instead of $U(N)$ because you have a term like $Tr(\phi^2)$ instead of $Tr(\phi^\dagger \phi)$.

Comment: you're right. So if you want to construct a gauge theory from this lagrangian you need to introduce covariant derivatives instead of the partial derivatives I assume.

Answer (score 3):

i) I'm afraid that's not right, a scalar can have components because in this context it is a *Lorentz* scalar. Nothing prevents you from having a collection of scalars. So your action is just a collection of scalar fields' Lagrangian.

ii) To deal with traces, you actually have to see with [The Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group#Fundamental_representation) for the special unitary groups. You have to differentiate with respect to $\phi^a$, not $\phi$ because as I said above, you have a collection of scalars (thus, you will have $N$ E.O.M.). Concretely, for $\text{SU}(N)$, you have:
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}(T_a T_b) = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{ab}
\end{equation}

Comment: This was very usefull. If I differentiate with respect to $\phi_a$ I find $(\Box-m)\phi^a(x)=0$, so every component of the scalar field satisfies the Klein-Gordon equation.